# iOS Custom modal presentation ignores supportedInterfaceOrientation

Tags: ios, animation, modal-dialog, uikit, orientation

I'm currently using a custom subclass of `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`to create a custom modal presentation. The problem I'm facing is when the presenting and presented view controllers support different interface orientations.

My situation is pretty simple. View Controller A supports all orientations. View Controller B only supports portrait. When A presents B while in landscape, B is presented in landscape.

This behavior can be fixed by switching from a custom modal presentation to a default presentation, which would imply that there is a way for the transitioning delegate to fix this behavior without some of the hacks that have been accepted on other answers.

What is the correct way of supporting different view controller orientations when creating custom modal animations?